# duplicate values in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am working on DB2.

There are duplicate rows in the table. I need to extract data where there is different value in 2nd column for same value in 1st column.

**there are column other than these in table but only need to consider these.**
for example:

| NBR | SE_NBR |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 56 |
| 123 | 56 |
| 123 | 56 |
| 248 | 75 |
| 248 | 75 |

To extract

| NBR | SE_NBR |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 12 |
| 456 | 34 |
| 456 | 11 |
| 135 | 77 |
| 135 | 88 |

Comment: `(123, 1), (123, 1), (123, 2)`. Do you need to extract the last row from such a set?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using window function:

```
select * from 
(
 select *, min(SE_NBR) over (partition by NBR) minnbr, max(SE_NBR) over (partition by NBR) maxnbr
 from nbrtable
) t
where minnbr <> maxnbr
```

if window function is not supported:

```
select * from tableName t1
where exists (
         select 1 from tablename t2 
         where t1.NBR = t2.NBR 
         group by t2.nbr 
         having count(distinct SE_NBR) > 1 
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=6c57e6b2142ced39e16d18a8f5ff34f2)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from t
where nbr in (
  select nbr from t group by nbr having count(distinct se_nbr) > 1
)
```